# Add Multiple Value array with Hashmap

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, hashmap

i tried so many things to do this, but still cant add more arraylist

please help me.

this is my code :

```
 public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> cartList;

    cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Get the position from the results
            HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
            resultp = data.get(position);
            cartList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("nama", resultp.get(SellerActivity.TITLE));
            map.put("harga", resultp.get(SellerActivity.HARGA));
            map.put("link_gambar", resultp.get(SellerActivity.WEBSITE));
            map.put("website", resultp.get(SellerActivity.GAMBAR));
            cartList.add(map);

        }
    });
```

i want the output is list of my arraylist, but on this situation i just can add one array.
thanks..

**UPDATE :**

now i want to add checkbox and button to delete item from arraylist, have a clue with that?

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and

Comment: @zacky it's unclear what you are asking

Comment: Question is unclear indeed.

Comment: thanks to anil, he's know what i mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create cartList each time when user click on cart. Maybe, the problem can be solved if you delete string `cartList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` from the `OnClick` and rewrite the first string of your sample code: `public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> cartList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>()`?

Comment: Not at all. But i recommend you ask more complete questions :)